# Create a grid of 3 X 3 using Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div class called box and this div forms a square.I want to repeat this div in order to form a 3 X 3 grid.How can i do this using for loop in javascript/jquery?

```
.box {
    background: #9E9E9E;
    border:black 1px solid;
    width: 180px;
    height:180px;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I was trying using append() but its not working! @sarjan Desai

Comment: display should be: 'inline-block' not 'block-inline'

Comment: I made that change @EaziLuizi

Comment: Telling us it's not working tells us nothing; show us your code, and explain in what way it's not working. How does it fail? Where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple (should be easy to understand) solution, change it as you wish according to your own needs:

**NOTE:** In future to not get your Question down-voted follow these [links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)...

**CSS:**

```
    .box {
        background: #9E9E9E;
        border: black 1px solid;
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    .row {
        display: block;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
```

**JS:**

```
    function makeBlocks() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement('div');
            row.className = "row";
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var box = document.createElement('div');
                box.className = "box";
                row.appendChild(box);
            }                
            document.getElementById('boxParent').appendChild(row);
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="boxParent"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="makeBlocks();">MAKE BLOCKS</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** 
Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/360otmLv/1/) link

Answer (score 1):

I give you a starting point:

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="toCopy">div that i have to clone</div>
</div>
```

```js
$( ".toCopy" ).clone().appendTo( ".parent" );
```

result:

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="toCopy">div that i have to clone</div>
 <div class="toCopy">div that i have to clone</div>
</div>
```

if you don't have class names, you can traverse the dom with jquery traversing: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Anyway I suggest you to check the manipulation section of the api: https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Thanks @Drway this works but this will not create 3 X 3 grid.How do I form that structure using multiple for loops.

Comment: I know, I just gave you the solution for the cloning. You have to nest 2 for, it's simple. Try alone, if you can't, I'll give you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sqz75b9g/8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="rows">
    <div class="row0"></div>
    <div class="row1"></div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$(function() {
    for(var row=0;row<3;row++)
    {
        for(var col=0;col<3;col++)
        {
            $(".row"+row).append("<div class='box'></div>");
        }
    }
})
```